# JScrollPane not working with FormLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, form-layout

I have a JPanel that uses FormLayout inside a JScrollPane.

For some reason, the JScrollPane does not show the scrollbars when the content gets too big.

I am new to Java, so I am most likely missing some minor thing :)

Here is my code so far. Resize the window to smaller height should cause the JScrollPane to show the scrollbars, but it does not. Please help!

I know that I should run the GUI in another thread etc, but this is just a mockup so far and it should not affect the result.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import com.jgoodies.forms.builder.PanelBuilder;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.CellConstraints;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;

public class Test7 extends JFrame {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Test7() {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Test7");
    this.setSize(1000, 700);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane_4 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    this.add(scrollPane_4);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

    scrollPane_4.setViewportView(container);

    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout("default", "fill:default:grow");
    PanelBuilder builder = new PanelBuilder(layout, container);
    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();

    layout.appendRow(new RowSpec("pref"));
    builder.add(bottom, cc.xy(1, layout.getRowCount()));        

    JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
    row1.setBackground(Color.decode("#fcfcfc"));
    row1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    row1.setAlignmentX(JPanel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    row1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    bottom.add(row1);

    JLabel lblAaaa = new JLabel("<html>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</html>");
    lblAaaa.setAlignmentY(JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    lblAaaa.setBackground(Color.decode("#f2f2f2"));
    lblAaaa.setOpaque(true);
    lblAaaa.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#cccccc"),1));
    row1.add(lblAaaa);

    layout.appendRow(new RowSpec("10px"));        

    JPanel bottom2 = new JPanel();
    bottom2.setOpaque(false);
    bottom2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    layout.appendRow(new RowSpec("pref"));
    builder.add(bottom2, cc.xy(1, layout.getRowCount()));        

    JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
    row2.setBackground(Color.decode("#fcfcfc"));
    row2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    row2.setAlignmentX(JPanel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    row2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    bottom2.add(row2);

    JLabel lblAaaa2 = new JLabel("<html>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</html>");
    lblAaaa2.setAlignmentY(JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    lblAaaa2.setBackground(Color.decode("#a9dff5"));
    lblAaaa2.setOpaque(true);
    lblAaaa2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#8fb4c2"), 1));
    row2.add(lblAaaa2);

    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test7();
}
}
```

UPDATE 1:

Following the tip from "Hovercraft", the scrollbars seems to work if I comment out the setPreferredSize row, but introduces another problem. The layout gets super-wide (outside the screen) and more. This might have to do with the setMaximumSize of row1 and row2, but I want to have a maximum size of those components :)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with layouts and all due to your you're limiting the size of the component JPanel here:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10)); // *****

scrollPane_4.setViewportView(container);
```

By calling `setPreferredSize(...)` your container JPanel will not get bigger than that size. Solution: don't do this, don't call `setPreferredSize(...)`. Either have your component size to its own natural preferred size that depend on the components it holds, or else override its `getPreferredSize()` method to return a size that makes sense, depending on the state of the GUI.

Comment: But if I comment out that line, the whole layout gets buggy. There must be some other problem as well then?

Comment: @DanieleTesta: yep, but that line is definitely the cause of your primary problem and will absolutely prevent your container JPanel from getting any larger. You've more work ahead of you.